# Rotate canvas along its center based on user touch - Android

Tags: android, rotation, html-canvas

I want to rotate the canvas circularly on its center axis based on user touch.

i want to rotate based on center but its rotating based on top left corner .

so i am able to see only 1/4 for rotation of image.

any idea..

Like a old phone dialer .

I have tried like as follows

```
onDraw(Canvas canvas){
  canvas.save();
  // do my rotation
  canvas.rotate(rotation,0,0);
  canvas.drawBitmap( ((BitmapDrawable)d).getBitmap(),0,0,p );
  canvas.restore();
}

@Override
        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
                  float x = e.getX();
              float y = e.getY();
              updateRotation(x,y);
              mPreviousX = x;
              mPreviousY = y;
            invalidate();
        }

  private void updateRotation(float x, float y) {

          double r = Math.atan2(x - centerX, centerY - y);
            rotation = (int) Math.toDegrees(r);
        }
```

Comment: First parameter to atan2 must be y in all implementations I know. Besides that, tell us where you are stuck. What is the problem?

Comment: i want to rotate based on center but its rotating based on top left corner . this is the issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The core problem in your code is probably that you pass in `0, 0` as the pivot point to rotate about in your rotate call.

For a more robust way of expressing your transformation, in linear algebra the way to rotate about an *arbitrary point* is to *translate* the world in such a way that the point is at the origin, *rotate*, and then *translate back*.

That is, `translate(-px, -py) * rotate(theta) * translate(px, py)`, where p is the point.

Answer (score 2):

You can find an example at installation of android sdk

```
android-sdks/add-ons/addon-google_apis-google_inc_-8/samples/MapDemo
```

But maybe you have to change a bit two method to get right orientation on touch event.

```
private class RotateView extends ViewGroup implements SensorListener {

/* ...  */

    private Matrix invertedMatrix = new Matrix();
    private float[] tempLocation = new float[2];


    @Override
    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.rotate(mHeading, getWidth() * 0.5f, getHeight() * 0.5f);
        canvas.getMatrix().invert(invertedMatrix);
        mCanvas.delegate = canvas;
        super.dispatchDraw(mCanvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        centeringAllowed = false;

        float[] location = tempLocation;
        location[0] = ev.getX();
        location[1] = ev.getY();
        invertedMatrix.mapPoints(location);
        ev.setLocation(location[0], location[1]);
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

This class is part of MapDemo project

Comment: This open source library for Android is perfect for the job
https://bitbucket.org/warwick/hacergestov3